# multiplier's individual delay is more than FIR filters delay as per synthesis report.Is it possible..?

Tags: vhdl

I m writing code with structural modeling in vhdl for 4 tap fir filter. In that i have used multiplier by port mapping.But multiplier's individual  delay is more than FIR filters delay as per synthesis report.Is it possible..?or something is wrong because there are some warnings in the report.Please help.

Comment: Yes it's possible. But there may be something wrong too. You need to read this [MCVE].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here we can help you with your coding issues. But in order to help you, you need to provide us with complete information. Please read ["How do I ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for reply:)